# Not all dll-s gets deployed from the MSI into IIS7

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, iis-7, windows-installer

We have a .NET web application with a web setup project that results an MSI. **The installer works fine for Win2003 IIS6.** However, if we run the same MSI under Win2008 IIS7, one of our dll-s does not get deployed. **We deploy 6 dll-s, 5 gets copied, one is ignored.** No errors reported during the installation process. If we manually copy the missing file to the destination folder, the application works. What can be the cause?

Comment: Post a log and the name of the DLL that got "ignored" and maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the cure to the problem, though we still do not understand why such strange symptoms are produced. When we compiled the MSI, the "forgotten" assembly was referenced by the deployed web site as a dll. We replaced the dll reference to project reference and rebuilt the MSI. This has fixed the issue.